# React navigation doesnt navigate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am developing an application and using the listener `onAuthStateChanged` from Firebase in my `AuthenticationLoadingScreen` so I can redirect the user based on this state, however, it just opens a white page and doesn't open the home screen.

**EDIT:** Someone says that maybe the `app.js` is the problem so I added it here

```
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen'
import AuthScreen from '../screens/AuthScreen'

// Implementation of HomeScreen, OtherScreen, SignInScreen, AuthLoadingScreen
// goes here.

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({ Home: HomeScreen});
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ Home: HomeScreen });

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthScreen,
    App: AppStack,
    Auth: AuthStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
));

export default class AuthScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
      super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount = ()=>{
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      this.props.navigation.navigate(user ? 'App' : 'Auth');

    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground
        source={require('../assets/images/AuthScreenBackground.png')}
        style={styles.ImageBackground}/>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the `App.js` code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import AppNavigation from './navigation/AppNavigation.js'


import * as firebase from 'firebase'

var config = {

  };
firebase.initializeApp(config);


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <AppNavigation/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.observeLogin = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
        } else {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
        }

    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    // Don't forget to unsubscribe when the component unmounts
    this.observeLogin ();
}
```

Comment: Can you put your App component code to your question? Because if it already moves to the different screen, it means the navigation work, the error from the component I think.